# curry function with n arguments

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

```
(curry-n f n)
```

f : a function that takes n arguments
n : a positive integer >=2
for example, let say

```
(define (add2 a b c d) (+ 2 a b c d))  
(define func (curry-n add2 4))
((((func 1) 2) 3) 4)
```

should produce 12.

I think I understand how curry works, for a binary function curry I can do something like

```
(define (curry-2 f)
 (lambda(x)
    (lambda(y)
     (f x y)))).
```

but I have trouble generalizing curry on n arguments, any help?

Answer (score 4):

You use a loop, of course. ;-) Here's my implementation:

```
(define (curry-n f n)
  (let loop ((n n) (args '()))
    (if (zero? n)
        (apply f (reverse args))
        (lambda (x)
          (loop (- n 1) (cons x args))))))
```

Here's a more general implementation that allows the curried functions to take any number of arguments, not just 1:

```
(define (curry-n f n)
  (let loop ((n n) (args '()))
    (if (zero? n)
        (apply f (reverse args))
        (lambda xs
          (let retry ((rem (- n (length xs))) (xs xs))
            (if (negative? rem)
                (retry 0 (take xs n))
                (loop rem (append-reverse xs args))))))))
```

(`take` and `append-reverse` are from [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html).)